# strictly positive iid random variables: a property

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be i.i.d and $>0\forall n$. Could anyone tell me how to show that $\mathbb P\left(\frac{X_{2n}}{X_{2n+1}}\ge 1 \text{ i.o}\right)=1$ Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Borel-Cantelli for independent events?

Comment: I don't know how to use it here in this situation. Thanks for the help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma as follows:

Note that since the $X_n$ are i.i.d. (so in particular independent), the sets $\{X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1}\} = \{\frac{X_{2n}}{X_{2n+1}} \geq 1\}$ are independent for any $n \in \mathbb{n}$.

Now we also have that for any $n \in \mathbb{n}$

$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1}\}) &= \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} > X_{2n + 1}\}) + \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} = X_{2n + 1}\}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1 - \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} = X_{2n + 1}\})) + \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} = X_{2n + 1}\}) \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$

where in the second line we used that the $X_n$ are i.i.d. and thus $\{X_{2n} > X_{2n + 1}\} = \{X_{2n+1} > X_{2n}\}$.

Now we have

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1}\}) \geq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} = \infty$$

Hence since the sets are independent, by Borel-Cantelli:

$$\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1}\}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1} ~~ \text{i.o.} \}) = 1$$

Comment: Your first displayed equations should be in terms of probabilities, not events. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: Of course, thanks. Edited.

Comment: Could you please tell me why did we not consider the set $\{ X_{2n}< X_{2n+1} \}$ in our analysis? Thanks.

Comment: We are interested in sets of the form $\{X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1}\} = \{\frac{X_{2n}}{X_{2n+1}} \geq 1\}$. However, in showing that $\mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} \geq X_{2n + 1}\} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ we use that $\mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} > X_{2n + 1}\} = \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2n} < X_{2n + 1}\}$.